# Why does JUnit not execute the whole method?

Tags: java, junit

How come the second Assert is never executed. I mean Assert does not throw an exception. So why is the method interrupted. It has no return value as well.

```
 @Test
 public void testReverse2()
 {   
     Assert.assertEquals(1.0, 2.0,0);

     Assert.assertEquals(4.0, 5.0,0);
 }
```

Comment: Your assumption("Assert does not throw an exception") is wrong. The first `Assert.assertEquals` throws an exception iff the assertion is not met

Comment: Your first Assert will throw an exception , so the second one will never be executed.

Comment: OK Thanks. So it stops executing because an Exception is thrown. Ok. That is the explanation I was looking for. But it seems to be a RuntimeException because it is not checked.

Comment: @Josephine no, it's an Error, an AssertionError specifically. Errors are also unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `assertEquals` does throw an Exception when it fails. In Your case it will always fail since You are comparing `1.0` with `2.0` with delta of `0.0`. So, it will always throw `AssertionError` and will never execute the second check.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation will interrupt if not equals and if you want to execute the whole assertion you can use `ErrorCollector`

*Note: **equalTo*** in org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers from `hamcrest` library

```
public class TargetTest {

    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void testReverse2() {   
        collector.checkThat(1.0, equalTo(2.0));
        collector.checkThat(4.0, equalTo(5.0));
    }
}
```